# Python: Calculate the average grade of all students that have the same subject

Tags: python, nested

I am a python **beginner** and made a task  for myself in order to get better at for and if statement's.
The task has the following criteria:

1. **load** data **from a .csv** file and **display it-the** 
   file contains data about the students first and last name, which subject they listen to and which 
   grade they have from 1 to 10
2. the user has the option to **enter a subject** and **if** the **subject exist** it **shows all the students who listen to the subject** it also shows the **average grade** of all the students who listen to the **subject**
3. should the **input** **not match** any of **the subjects** it displays a **error message and doesn't show the average grade  of a subject**.

**I displayed the data and enabled searching  by subject, but can't figure out how to not show the average grade if the input if different from the existing subjects.**

The file is named students.csv and it contains:

```
John;Doe;Informatics;4
Max;King;Biology;3
Tim;Lambert;Computer Science;2
Anna;Gray;Geography;6
Megan;Hart;Englisch;7
Phil;Hill;German;8
Audrey;Ava;Informatics;3
Bella;Carol;Informatics;7
Diana;Diane;Englisch;2
Bella;Bernadette;Englisch;1
Carolyn;Chloe;Biology;9
Carol;Caroline;Biology;8
Elizabeth;Ella;Geography;3
```

This is my task_2.py Python(3.8.1) code:

```
#open the file and create a list
work_file  = open("students.csv","r")
students = []
#print(work_file)

#create a sublist
for row in work_file:
    row = row.rstrip()
    row_sublist = row.split(";")
    students.append(row_sublist)

#ordered heading
print("--------------")
print("About the students: ")
print("--------------")
print("{0:18}{1:18}{2:18}{3:18}".format("Name","Last","Subject","Grade"))
print("{0:18}{1:18}{2:18}{3:18}".format("----","----","-------","-----"))

#print
for bundle in students:
    for data in bundle:
        print("{0:17}".format(data), end=" ")
    print()

print()#/n
#input
question = input("Witch subject do u wont to know mmore about? ")

#initialize
counter = 0
grade = 0
average = 0
valid = ""

#search
for bundle in students:
    if question == bundle[2]:
        valid = "yes"
        grade = grade + int(bundle[3])
        counter = counter + 1
        average = grade/counter
        for data in bundle:
            print("{0:17}".format(data), end=" ")
        print()

#print average
print("The average is: ", average)

#print the
if valid != "yes":
   print("Error")

#close
work_file.close()
```

*Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time and have a great day.*

Edit: changed witch to which

Comment: As a minor note, the english word "witch" refers to a kind of magic user; the word you're looking for is "which" :)

Comment: Yes u are right, thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. You're Soo close. 
Just make a tiny change like this.

From this

```
#print average 
print("The average is: ", average) 
#print the 
if valid != "yes": 
  print("Error")
```

To this

```
#print the 
if valid != "yes": 
  print("Error")
else:
  print("The average is: ", average)
```

TBH, hard to believe you're new. 
Pretty sure if you do go through all concepts, you'll be an expert in short amount of time.

Comment: Your changes are working perfectly, didn't think it was that easy. Thank u very much for your help and the motivational advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the average output in an if statement:

```
if valid == "yes":
    print("The average is: ", average)
```

Comment: It's working great and exactly as it should thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import statistics
# Try these modules

# Get the question  first
subject = input("Which subject do u want to know more about? ")

# Read the file
student_file = open('students.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(student_file, delimiter=';')

# Find Students who take same subject
same_subject_students = []
for row in reader:
    if subject.lower() == str(row[2]).lower():
        same_subject_student = [row[0], row[1], row[2], int(row[3])]
        same_subject_students.append(same_subject_student)

# Check if any students take same subject and print them along with their average grade
if len(same_subject_students) > 0:
    print("--------------")
    print("About the students: ")
    print("--------------")
    print("{0:18}{1:18}{2:18}{3:18}".format("Name", "Last", "Subject", "Grade"))

    grades = []
    for student in same_subject_students:
        grades.append(student[3])
        print("{0:18}{1:18}{2:18}{3:5}".format(student[0], student[1], student[2], student[3]))

    print("Their average is grade: %.2f" % statistics.mean(grades))
else:
    print("No Student is taking", subject)

student_file.close()
```

Comment: It is working perfectly, thank you for showing an entire different approach and coding it.